# SQL Can you Sum Sales based on Weekday?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have Sales throughout the Year and I want to know on which weekdays it was the busiest based on the sales of that day.

I am pretty new to SQL so..

For Example, it looks like this:

```
Date        Sales   CompanyID

14.10.2020  20      12
14.10.2020  10      2
15.10.2020  15      19
15.10.2020  6       4
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
Weekday   Sales

Wednesday 30
Thursday  21
```

I think I have to use the sum() function on sales and order it by weekdays with date ?

Comment: What does this have to do with `jQuery` ?

Comment: Changed it, sorry about that. miss clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TO_CHAR` with appropriate format mask. For example (in which sample data is in lines #1 - 6; query you need begins at line #7):

```
SQL> with test (datum, sales, companyid) as
  2    (select date '2020-10-14', 20, 12 from dual union all
  3     select date '2020-10-14', 10,  2 from dual union all
  4     select date '2020-10-15', 15, 19 from dual union all
  5     select date '2020-10-15',  6,  4 from dual
  6    )
  7  select to_char(datum, 'fmDay') day,
  8    sum(sales) sales
  9  from test
 10  group by to_char(datum, 'fmDay');

DAY            SALES
--------- ----------
Wednesday         30
Thursday          21

SQL>
```

Comment: Couldn't I just use from the beginning of line 7 ?
I don't really understand the first part

Comment: so this should be right i think 

select to_char(date_column, 'Day') date_column,
sum(sales) sales
from table
group by to_char(date_column, 'Day');

Comment: That's exactly what I said. Lines 1-6 represent sample data; as I don't have your table, I used the CTE (common table expression) a.k.a. the WITH factoring clause so that I'd have some data to work with.

Comment: ähm, is it normal that the sum() function brings shows something with an Delimiter even tho the entries are all int ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Which "delimiter"? Where?